# how to reference a package in another package having GO111MODULE=on in go

Tags: go, package

If i have the below structure:

```
HelperFolder
    Library1
        lib1.go
    Library2
        lib2.go
        file2.go
```

Where lib1.go imports Library2.

I have executed go mod init in library2 and then go mod tidy and then go build and all is fine.
But I can't get Library1 built.

I do not want to install any of the libraries, or place the libraries in gopath (i have placed the HelperFolder in a different path) but i always get the error in building library1 that package2 is not in GOROOT(C:\program files\go\src\package2)

What am I missing?

any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to use replace directive in go.mod of `Library1` when referencing other module which isn't hosted. e.g. `replace Library2 => ../Library2` after the `require` stuff.

Comment: @Zyl thank you for the help. i have used something like "go mod edit replace HelperFolder/Lib2 => D:\folderPath\HelperFolder\Lib2", then "go get HelperFolder/Lib2" and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

A Go module may contain many packages. The main reason to define multiple modules is so that you can version and release the packages in those modules on separate release schedules. For local-only (unpublished, unversioned) packages, it is pretty much always simpler to instead use a single unified module.

That is: run `go mod init` just once in `HelperFolder` rather than twice in the individual `Library` folders.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zyl noted in his comment, i used the following go commands:

```
go mod edit replace HelperFolder/Lib2 => D:\folderPath\HelperFolder\Lib2
```

Then

```
go get HelperFolder/Lib2
```